# ¿cómo puedo colocar la fecha actual como mínimo en datepicker?

Tags: html, jquery

lo que sucede es que necesito colocar como minimo la fecha actual en un date picker lo he intentado de la siguiente forma paro nada.

```js
$(document).ready(function (params) {

    $('#vencimiento_producto').datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(fechaActual())
    });
 });
 
 function fechaActual() {
    var d = new Date();
    var strDate = d.getFullYear() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
    return strDate;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
                <label  class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Fecha Vencimiento Producto:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input required type="text" class="form-control vencimiento_producto" id= "vencimiento_producto" name="descripcion_producto" placeholder="Descripcion Producto">
                </div>
            </div>
```

agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que te sirva de ayuda:

```
$('#vencimiento_producto').datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hombre